# You do not have permission to view this directory or page. Azure Web Api

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, window, swagger

I have a web api project with documentation (swagger) folder in the root  of project [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk3wS.jpg) 
On local I can view page with route like

```
http://localhost:9941/documentation/
```

But when i deploy this project to azure its given me permission error by same url in deploy

```
http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/documentation/
```

*Error message:*

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Web config

```
 <system.web>       
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />       
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Did you look at the Authentication/Authorization settings in your App Service?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incomplete deployment of you application. Restarting or deleting and re-uploading should resolve the issue.